# UWP xaml binding command to grid onfocus

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

In a UWP Windows 10 application I'm working on have a command in my Viewmodel

```
public class ViewModel {
     public ICommand LoadedCommand{ get; set; } 
}
```

and I'd like to run it when my grid control gets the focus, without having to call the command in the code behind file.

```
<Grid GotFocus="Grid_GotFocus">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Does anyone know if its possible to assign the command to the event directly in the xaml and if it is how I might do it.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either the `InvokeCommandAction` from the [XAML Behavior library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed/), or use **`x:Bind` to event** that's available in the Anniversary Update. So you can have something like -

```
GotFocus="{x:Bind Vm.OnGridGotFocus}"
```

Note the `OnGridGotFocus()` here is a method and it can either have no parameters or matdch the signiture of the event.